# Error : module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'read_file'

Tags: python, pip, geopandas

I'm using for several weeks geopandas on Python.

It worked well until yesterday, I believe until I reinstalled another package for geographic data.

Now, I can still import geopandas, but when I execute :

```
my_data = gpd.read_file(path_data + "my_data.geojson")
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-fb224ec85b60>", line 1, in <module>
    my_data = gpd.read_file(path_data + "my_data.geojson")

AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'read_file'
```

I tried to uninstall geopandas (`pip uninstall geopandas`) and reinstall it (`conda install geopandas`), but it doesn't work better.

Anyone knows what's happenning and what could I do ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What is your file name?

Comment: in my code, instead of "my_data" it is : pav_lieu = gpd.read_file(path_data + "open_data/collecte_dechets/pav.geojson")

Comment: I am sorry, that was ambiguous, I was pointing to the name of the python script

Comment: ok, my script is called "observation_data.py"

Comment: What is your python version and geopandas version

Comment: I use Python 3.7 and geopandas 0.7.0 (but here is perhaps the problem, because on my Anaconda board it is written 0.7.0, but in the folder with all downloaded packages, I have these 2 folders : geopandas-0.6.1-py_0 and geopandas-0.6.3-py_0)

Comment: I do not know geopandas, but it seems to me you might have a version of geopandas which does not have the function you mention. Try to install the right version of geopandas.

Comment: Yes, I had understood that but didn't achieve to reinstall correctly geopandas. But now it works !

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it wasn't too complicated : I removed geopandas, but this time I closed Spyder and Anaconda and then re-opened them, and I've could then reinstall it effectively !